# how to enumerate array indices as odd and even numbers in parameters part of omnet.ini

Tags: omnet++

I have this parameter as an array. The array is big, 100 cells. It is a parameter that can be initiated in omnet.ini file. The cells with even numbers should get value A and odd numbers should get value B. How can I do this in an automated manner?

Is there a way besides having all odd and even indices initiated one by one manually?

Wildcards can be useful but I do not know how to use them to separate odd and even indices.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the actual module index with the `index` operator. Combining this with the conditional operator `?:` you can easily define the value:

```
**.myModule[*].myParameter = index % 2 == 0 ? "A" : "B"
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm not aware of any feature like this. There are a number of work-arounds you could use:

1. Provide two parameters and select the correct one in code
2. Use the `volatile` keyword (probably not appropriate here)
3. Put the entire thing in your `.ini` file

I'd personally implement the first approach, that way you can use the wildcard to pass both parameters (`[*].myNode.parameterEven` and `[*].myNode.parameterUneven`) and then set the correct values in your array in a for loop.

However, you could also use the volatile keyword in your NED file, see [the manual](https://omnetpp.org/doc/omnetpp/manual/usman.html#sec156) for more details. However, this approach mostly works well if you have different parameters depending on which node you are assigning it to. For this case I think the first approach is better.

The last alternative is just putting the entire thing in your `.ini` file, which may be useful if you want to parameterize the array later.